# python requests module iteration

Tags: python

I was doing a coding challenge and noticed something weird with how arrays worked with modules (or more likely it's my own error).

```
pages = [*list of 5 webpages*]
final = []

for i in range(0,4):
    page = requests.get(pages[i])
    piece = page.text
    final.append(piece)

print(''.join(final))
```

This code only joins 4 of the 5 webpages. Changing the range to `0,5` or `len(pages)` solves the problem. I was under the impression that `0,4` would include all the webpages in my list (5 of them) since indexing starts at 0.

Comment: Why are you iterating over indices? Just iterate over the pages directly? `for page in pages: page = requests.get(page)`

Comment: Python `range` doesn't include the "end" value, so `range(x, y)` means `x, x+1, x+2, ..., y-2, y-1`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is *pythonic* and more robust in a sense that it does not depend on the number of pages:

```
pages = [*list of 5 webpages*]
final = [requests.get(page).text for page in pages]
print(''.join(final))
```